# Batch files: Copy files to all subfolders

Tags: windows, loops, for-loop, batch-file, copy

I'm trying to copy 3 files to all the subfolders of the folder A1. I tryed something like this:

```
for %%v in (A1/*.*) do (
    COPY command.bat A1\%%v
    COPY CUS.jar A1\%%v
    COPY input.txt A1\%%v
)
```

But, looks like this %%v only function for files and not subdirectories... :-(

Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
for /f %%v in ('dir "path_to_A1" /AD /B /ON') do (
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for /d %%v in ("A1\*") do (
```